# How to use Intel C++ Compiler with Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-construction, integration, intel

I am writing a program wherein i will need to do a stupendous number of numerical calculations. But since I am developing the front end of the program in Qt Creator, I have as yet been dealing with MinGW.

As such, is there any way to integrate or use the Intel C++ Compiler with QT Creator?

Currently using IC++ 11.0 and QtCreator 1.2.1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think so but you need to rebuild / reconfigure Qt Creator as documented in the [Deploying an Application on Windows](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/deployment-windows.html) section.  And looking into the `mkspecs` directory, I see 'win32-icc' which is probably what you need.

*Edit:* To clarify, you may need the whole 'SDK' rather than just the creator, and you need to then re-configure Qt within `qt/` directoty of the SDK file tree using

```
configure -platform win32-icc
```

plus whatever other options you may need.  It also takes a little while to build this, and as `icc` isn't know for its compilation speed you may want to give this a couple of hours to a day.

Comment: I don't see any connection between the article `Deploying an Application on Windows` and using Intel C++ compiler in Qt Creator. However, the second part of the advice (to use `win32-icc` platform description/configuration file) is ok.

Comment: Well the 'Deploying ...' part shows how to run configure with a new specification and it happens to be the page I turned to when I needed static libs.   Also note that OP is on Windows.

Comment: I have the whole SDK and will follw up on this suggestion.

Will update once i try.
Thanks

Comment: Please do -- I'd be very curious to hear what you find.

Comment: ***UPDATE*** I have started building with icc but just as an update to anyone who wishes to try this, since the intel compilers are know for their optimizations and so the build process is taking a LONG time.

Answer (score 3):

If you're concerned about compiler performance for some of your code but want to use a development tool that doesn't integrate with your desired compiler, isn't the saner answer to use the Intel compiler to generate a DLL called by your Qt program?

And as with all performance question: have you benchmarked your code to be sure that the compiler optimization is actually the limit?  Have you investigated other options, like a hardware upgrade or some targetted assembly code?  Whacking at an unmeasured performance problem by changing tools usually just leads to wasted work.

Comment: I had not thought of using a DLL. But otherwise, i have bechmarked the performance and the intel compiler is significantly faster.
The issue is that the program does a numerical interpretation and modification of various image files. So while icould theoritically write an assembly code, that would imply that about 75% of my code is in assembly (of which i have little experience). also the numercal computations are not, in themselves, simple.
But thanks for the suggestion and i will check out the DLL option.